# как после 'Место' получить текст от пользователя и снова появились кнопки

Tags: python, telebot

Подскажите. Мне после нажатия кнопки 'Место' нужно получить тест от пользователя, после введения должны снова появится кнопки. В финале  после нескольких таких кнопок сформировать в одно сообщение и вывести заявку где будет находится введённый тест после кнопок 'Место','Дата','Оплата за час'.

```
import telebot

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('сделать заказ')
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton('я ищу работу')

    markup.add(item1, item2)
    mess = 'Здравствуйте, <b>{0.first_name}!</b>'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess.format(message.from_user), parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'сделать заказ':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Место')
            back = types.KeyboardButton('⬅️Назад')
            markup.add(item1, back)
            mess1 = '<b>Создайте заявку</b>'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess1.format(message.from_user), parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == 'я ищу работу':
            mess2 = 'присоединитесь к каналу '
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess2)
        elif message.text == '⬅️Назад':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton('сделать заказ')
            item2 = types.KeyboardButton('я ищу работу')
            markup.add(item1, item2)
            mess = '<b>⬅️Назад</b>'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess.format(message.from_user), parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == 'Место':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Дата')
            back = types.KeyboardButton('⬅️Назад')
            markup.add(item1, back)
            mess3 = 'Вы выберите место: ' + message.text
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess3)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение нужно использовать FSM состояние. О нем подробнее можно найти в гайдах

Comment: Это замечательно, что самостоятельно разобрались в вопросе, но ответ сейчас не подходит для stackoverflow. Добавьте больше информации и ссылки. Подробнее: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы](/help/how-to-answer).